# Comparing First Element of Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I am reading in a csv file line by line and splitting them using the Split() function. This portion works fine, however, I am only really searching for lines that begin with "MONITORED". When I try to compare the first element of the array, I get a subscript out of range error.

```
Open Fname For Input As #1
  iRow = 1
  Line Input #1, Record
  Do Until EOF(1)
     P = Split(Record)

    If P(0) = "MONITORED" Then
        For i = LBound(P) To UBound(P)
            Cells(iRow, i + 1) = P(i)
        Next i
     Else
        iRow = iRow - 1
     End If

     iRow = iRow + 1
     Line Input #1, Record
  Loop
  Close 1
```

Comment: What is `Record`?

Comment: If Instr(LTrim$(Record,"M"))=1 then. Also the default seperator for split is a space. If record is comma seperated values you''l need to specify this in the split statement.

Comment: Record is a line in the file

Comment: Upon which line do you get a `Subscript out of range` error? Also it seems like you should increment `iRow` inside your `If` not inside your `else` but maybe I'm just misunderstanding.

Comment: I realise that, what's its value?

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) on `If P(0) = ...`, run the code, and when the breakpoint is hit bring up the *Locals* toolwindow (from the *View* menu) and in there you will be able to see the current value of `Record` and each element of `P`; hit F8 to step through, shift+F8 to step over, and F5 to resume.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes:

```
Open Fname For Input As #1
iRow = 1

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Record
    If Record Like "MONITORED*" Then
        p = Split(Record, ",")
        Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1, UBound(p) + 1) = p
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
Loop
Close 1
```